# Unity: 'Physics' does not contain a definition for 'CheckSphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a part of my code to Ground Check in Unity

```
bool isGrounded;
void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
    }
```

It's showing error "'Physics' does not contain a definition for 'CheckSphere"
I checked and Physics does contain CheckSphere

Comment: What's the full error message? What types are `groundCheck.position`, `groundDistance` and `groundMask` ?

Comment: That's the full error message,    public CharacterController controller;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` **not** in `unityscript` which is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like language used in previous Unity versions and is long deprecated by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make Sure no other class in your Project ist calles "Physics" and that "Physics" referes to UnityEngine.Physics

Comment: Ok, I had named my file as Physics.cs, renamed it. Works fine, Thank you!